# Magento SOAP connection send ProtocolException was unhandled

Tags: api, soap

In my first magento to api connection (SOAP) programme it says that it has ProtocolException was handheld by user code. Here is the full exception error

----------------------------ERROR---------------------------------------------------------

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087 Message=The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   of the response message does not match the content type of the binding
>   (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 361
>   bytes of the response were: '
>     0
>   SOAP extension is not loaded.
>     '.
>   Source=mscorlib StackTrace: Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   SOAPTesting.ServiceReference2.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType.login(String
>   username, String apiKey) at
>   SOAPTesting.ServiceReference2.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient.login(String
>   username, String apiKey) in g:\VISUAL STUDIO 2013 PROJECT
>   WORKSPACE\HarshiniPROJECT\SOAPTesting\SOAPTesting\Service
>   References\ServiceReference2\Reference.cs:line 29488 at
>   SOAPTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in g:\VISUAL STUDIO 2013
>   PROJECT
>   WORKSPACE\HarshiniPROJECT\SOAPTesting\SOAPTesting\Program.cs:line 16
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args) at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException:

------------------ CODING--------------------------------------------------------------

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient mservice = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
        string mlogin = mservice.login("dileepa", "takastakas");

        Debug.WriteLine(mlogin);
        filters mf = new filters();
        complexFilter[] cpf = new complexFilter[1];
        complexFilter mcpf = new complexFilter();
        mcpf.key = "increment_id";
        associativeEntity mas = new associativeEntity();
        mas.key = "gt";
        mas.value = "1008001";
        mcpf.value = mas;
        cpf[0] = mcpf;
        mf.complex_filter = cpf;
        salesOrderListEntity[] soe = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, mf);
        if (soe.Length > 0)
        {

            foreach (salesOrderListEntity msoe in soe)
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("" + msoe.billing_firstname + " " + msoe.subtotal);
                }
                catch (Exception merror)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("" + msoe.order_id + "" + merror.ToString());
                }
            }
        }



        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SOAP extension is not loaded.

That should give you an idea. The server where your magento instance is placed is missing the `php_soap` extension.
enable it and it should work.